# mongo find multiple array pairs

Tags: mongodb

If I have an array of pairs like so:

```
[
  {foo: 'a', bar: 'b'},
  {foo: 'b', bar: 'c'},
  {foo: 'a', bar: 'd'},
  {foo: 'b', bar: 'b'},
]
```

And I want to find documents in a collection that match any of these pairs exactly, how do I do this?

I've looked at the $in, $all, $elemMatch operators but none of them seem to quite do what I want.

I could do the queries individually:

```
db.baz.find({foo: 'a', bar: 'b'})
db.baz.find({foo: 'b', bar: 'c'})
db.baz.find({foo: 'a', bar: 'd'})
db.baz.find({foo: 'b', bar: 'b'})
```

But what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
db.baz.find([
  {foo: 'a', bar: 'b'},
  {foo: 'b', bar: 'c'},
  {foo: 'a', bar: 'd'},
  {foo: 'b', bar: 'b'},
]);
```

Comment: Have you considered using the aggregation framework?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Does the above represent an array element within a document, or are these documents in a collection in themselves? You likely want `$elemMatch` but are doing it wrong. Show what you are doing and your expected output, along with some context to how this is actually represented as already mentioned. Right now it's not clear what you are asking/trying or what you expect.

Comment: @BlakesSeven see edits

Comment: This appears to be "documents" rather than an "array" if those individual queries are returning results for you. If so then just use [`$or`.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the $or syntax:

```
db.baz.find({
    $or: [
        { foo: 'a', bar: 'b' },
        { foo: 'b', bar: 'c' },
        { foo: 'a', bar: 'd' },
        { foo: 'b', bar: 'b' },
    ]
})
```

Comment: Any idea how the performance of this query compares to doing them individually?

Comment: I don't have a huge sample collection to try.... but reads in mongo are VERY fast in general.  In many of my production instances we do 60k reads a second.  Since this is all handled inside mongo with the $or clause I would imagine it is efficient.